# lint error 18 "Symbol 'CsiNetInit(void)' redeclared (precision) conflicts with line 21

Tags: c, lint

Can any please explain in which scenarios will we get these errors?

I have a following code and lint is showing following error:

```
#ifdef SIC_CSI_NET
short CsiNetInit(void);
#endif
```

Error:

> "Symbol 'CsiNetInit(void)' redeclared (precision) conflicts with line 21

There is nothing in line 21 I can see a ** which is used for comment.

Comment: Instead of our imagining scenarios, why not show us line 21?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, in one of the compilation units processing these lines, `SIC_CSI_NET` is not defined, in contrast to the file provoking this warning, but the function is used. In that case, Lint doesn't see a prototype at all, brings a different warning (probably 718 "Symbol 'CsiNetInit' undeclared, assumed to return int"), and assumes a prototype `int CsiNetInit(void);`.

When it then sees the actual prototype, the difference becomes obvious: `int` vs. `short`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the actual definition of `CsiNetInit()`; perhaps its prototype specifies a different return type than `short`?